# SQLAlchemy 2 columns with same foreign key 1 relationship - OR query?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have two tables `teams` and `matches` (has more columns than shown but these are enough for this example):

```
class Teams(DBBase):
    __tablename__ = 'teams'
    team_id = Column(
        sqlalchemy.INTEGER,
        primary_key=True,
        autoincrement=False)
    sport_id = Column(
        sqlalchemy.INTEGER,
        sqlalchemy.ForeignKey("sports.sport_id"),
        index=True)
    team_type_id = Column(
        sqlalchemy.INTEGER,
        sqlalchemy.ForeignKey("team_types.team_type_id"),
        index=True)
    country_id = Column(
        sqlalchemy.INTEGER,
        sqlalchemy.ForeignKey("countries.country_id"),
        index=True)

class Matches(DBBase):
    __tablename__ = 'matches'
    match_id = Column(
        sqlalchemy.INTEGER,
        primary_key=True,
        autoincrement=False)
    team_0_id = Column(
        sqlalchemy.INTEGER,
        sqlalchemy.ForeignKey("teams.team_id"),
        index=True)
    team_1_id = Column(
        sqlalchemy.INTEGER,
        sqlalchemy.ForeignKey("teams.team_id"),
        index=True)
    venue_id = Column(
        sqlalchemy.INTEGER,
        sqlalchemy.ForeignKey("venues.venue_id"),
        index=True)
```

I would like to be able to access all of a team's matches, whether they are `team_0` or `team_1` (think home or away).

In raw SQL I could do something like:

`SELECT * FROM matches WHERE team_0_id = 'insert team id here' OR team_1_id = 'insert team id here'`

or I think even more optimally (speedwise):

```
SELECT * FROM matches WHERE team_0_id = 'insert team id here' 
UNION
SELECT * FROM matches WHERE team_1_id = 'insert team id here'
```

Now I am wondering what is the correct (if there is one) way to create a `relationship` on my `Teams` class?

I came up with the following:

```
matches = relationship('Matches', primary_join="or_(Teams.team_id==Matches.team_0_id, Teams.team_id==Matches.team_1_id")
```

However this won't make use of `UNION`. I also wondered if this is perhaps just bad table/DB design and I should have some sort of association table between matches and teams instead?

Answer (score -1):

You can use union here, via the ORM's [Query.union](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html?highlight=union#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.union)

```
home_query = session.query(Matches).filter(Matches.team_0_id == 1)

away_query = session.query(Matches).filter(Matches.team_1_id == 1)

all_matches_where_team_participated = home_query.union(away_query).all()
```

Where `session` is created from [sessionmaker](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html?highlight=sessionmaker#sqlalchemy.orm.session.sessionmaker)